# Visual Studio 2008 Menu Items Duplicated

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I occasionally get some issues with Visual Studio and ReSharper that causes me to run

```
devenv.exe /ResetSettings
```

After doing this, the menu items under "Data" are all duplicated, and each section is duplicated. So it now looks like this:

```
Show Data Sources
Add New Data Source...
-------------------------
Schema Compare
Schema Compare
Data Compare
Data Compare
-------------------------
Schema Compare
Schema Compare
Data Compare
Data Compare
-------------------------
Refactor
Refactor
-------------------------
Refactor
Refactor
-------------------------
T-SQL Editor
T-SQL Editor
-------------------------
T-SQL Editor
T-SQL Editor
-------------------------
Static Code Analysis
-------------------------
Schema View
```

I have the MS Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edition GDR 2 installed, and I think that is what's causing the issue.

Is there a way to remove the duplicated items, or better yet, stop this from happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819149.aspx) which seems to illustrate your problem and how to fix it.

FTA

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio Team System 2008 editions.
2. At the Windows Command Prompt, type the following command:

   > %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\DBPro\DBProRepair.exe RemoveDBPro2008
3. Press ENTER.
4. At the Windows Command Prompt, type the following command:

> %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /ResetUser

Comment: Btw, /ResetUser wasn't a valid option, which was strange. I just did /ResetSettings and that worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the whole ResetSettings and it didn't work.  What I did do that worked for me was:

(All in directory Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio)
1.) Copy the 10.0 directory somewhere where you can reference it later
2.) Delete the 10.0 directory.
3.) Boot Visual Studio 2010 and voila!

All my plugins and everything were still intact.  I'm not sure what side-effects there will be, and I didn't have a terribly customized environment.

Comment: Had this problem with VS2008, and yours is the only solution here which worked for me -- I renamed the "9.0" folder to "9.0_old" - thanks! -- The problem occurred after installing nVidia nSight.

Comment: This worked for me (VS2012), only difference was deleting the 11.0 folder instead of 10.0.

Answer (score 1):

After calling

```
DBProRepair.exe RemoveDBPro2008
```

the menu entry "Data" in Visual Studio was disappeared. I had to run

```
DBProRepair.exe RestoreDBPro2008
```

to get it back in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Run this:

```
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /safemode /setup
```

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd in admin mode 
Change dir to dev instal path
Run below command . ( but it will reset your initial settings , like c# preference  setting on starting – that’s not a big issue I think )   
Devenv.exe /resetuserdata